# como obter uma lista do fim para o início?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Listas iniciais:

```
B_I = ['Cab', 'Bou', 'Bou', 'RFF', 'RF1', 'Rf2', 'Cor']
Ba_F = ['Bou', 'Zez1', 'Zez2', 'Praca', 'Sro', 'Sro', 'Falag']
```

Depois fiz ........

```
Final=[] #lista com todos os barramentos sem repetir inicial e final
for a in range (0,len(Ba_I)):
    if (Ba_I[a] not in Final and Ba_I[a]!=0):
        Final.append(Ba_I[a])
for b in range (0,len(Ba_F)):
    if (Ba_F[b] not in Final and Ba_F[b]!=0):
        Final.append(Ba_F[b])
B_I_final = [Final.index(i) for i in B_I]
Ba_F_final = [Final.index(i) for i in Ba_F]
```

E dá:

```
B_I_final = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Ba_F_final = [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10]
```

E agora precisava de obter também o contrário de B_I_final e de Ba_F_final..
Tentei fazer:

```
b_contr=[] 
for x in B_I_final[::-1]: 
    b_contr.append(B_I_final[x])
```

e para o B_I_final dá-me isto:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

e devia dar:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras de se fazer, mas eu acho que a maneira mais rápida é:

```
invertido=B_I_final[::-1]
```

Não precisa colocar `for` nada, ela vai ficar inversa.

Outra alternativa é utilizar `reverse()`:

```
invertido=B_I_final.reverse()
```

se você quer colocar dentro de um `for` utilize a função `reversed`

```
b_contr=[] 
for i in reversed(B_I_final):
        b_contr.append(i)
```